# Callback for chrome.tabs.insertCSS doesn't execute when allFrames:true is used

Tags: google-chrome-extension

As basic as it gets in background.js of a Chrome extension:

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {
        file: "widget.css",
        allFrames: true
    }, function () {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
        console.log("Inserted CSS in tab " + tab.id);
    });
```

Take out the allFrames argument (or set it to false) and the console shows the expected message, *Inserted CSS in tab 1234* and I can see the changes to formatting on the target page. Set it to true and... nothing. No errors, no timeouts, just silence and tumbleweeds in the console of the extension.

If I reload the page or navigate to a different URL in the same tab, I see the *Inserted* message suddenly pop into the console and then it continues with loading whatever new content was asked for.

Manifest permissions include:

```
"permissions": ["<all_urls>", "tabs", "activeTab"],
"web_accessible_resources": ["*.js","*.css"]
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug rather than a problem in your code. Try searching through https://crbug.com and create an issue if it's not there yet; don't forget to link to it here.

Comment: Good call @Xan -- bug found here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=533863&q=callback&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified and was able to reproduce exactly. An iframe that returns a 204 hangs the load complete event. Bug is assigned, the wait begins I guess?

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in Chrome v50.